# Update for Deprecated setLayerInsertionPoint() in QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis-3

The setLayerInsertionPoint() with the QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot() object is deprecated.  The documentation says:

```
since QGIS 3.10 use setLayerInsertionPoint( const InsertionPoint &insertionPoint ) instead
```

but I can find no example of how to implement this update.  My current code is as follows:

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRegistryBridge().setLayerInsertionPoint(QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), 0)
```

It seems the only change is the first argument.  How should I update the statement to comply with current requirements?

`QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRegistryBridge().setLayerInsertionPoint([what_goes_here?], 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not actually tested this but the following should work:

```py
root_group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

insertion_point = QgsLayerTreeRegistryBridge.InsertionPoint(root_group, 0)

QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRegistryBridge().setInsertionPoint(insertion_point)
```

To check, the line:

```py
print(insertion_point)
```

returns:

```py
<qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeRegistryBridge.InsertionPoint object at 0x000001DAE4116678>
```

See:

https://qgis.org/api/structQgsLayerTreeRegistryBridge_1_1InsertionPoint.html

Comment: This method works swimmingly.  Thank you.